# Github - How to merge to remote feature branch

Tags: github, version-control, pull-request, git-pull

My team mate created a feature branch from our master branch. I created my own feature branch based off of team mate's feature branch. i.e.

Team mate:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b teammateA-feature-branch
```

What I did:

```
git checkout teammateA-feature-branch
git pull
git checkout -b teammateB-feature-branch
```

I made my changes into teammateB-feature-branch and committed them.
Now, how would I create a PR such that my committed changes gets merged to team mate's remote branch i.e. teammateB-feature-branch merging into teammateA-feature-branch??
Any thoughts??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this locally using Git bash:

```
git checkout teammateA-feature-branch
git merge teammateB-feature-branch
```

Then, push changes to `teammateA-feature-branch`:

```
git push origin teammateA-feature-branch:teammateA-feature-branch
```

#### OR

If these branches are available remotely (and locally), you can do the following:

1. Go to the pull requests tab in your repository.
2. Click on the Compare button.
3. Compare `teammateA-feature-branch` with `teammateB-feature-branch`.
4. Create your pull request.
5. Merge your changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot..did you mean "git push origin teammateA-feature-branch:teammateB-feature-branch" OR "git push origin teammateB-feature-branch:teammateA-feature-branch"?

Comment: NVM.."git push origin teammateB-feature-branch:teammateA-feature-branch" worked for me..Thanks a lot

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean't using `git push origin teammateA-feature-branch:teammateA-feature-branch`, but `git push origin teammateB-feature-branch:teammateA-feature-branch` should work fine, too. 